# Linux Yum Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version

Tags: linux, bash, centos, yum, pycurl

So this error is driving me crazy, I've search the web multiple times, ran a few things and no results. I get the following error when using yum.

```
[root@texas pycurl-7.19.0]# yum update
Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-timeversion
Aborted


[root@texas pycurl-7.19.0]# rpm -qa | grep pycurl
python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.i686
[root@texas pycurl-7.19.0]# rpm -qa | grep curl
curl-7.19.7-26.el6_2.4.i686
libcurl-7.19.7-26.el6_2.4.i686
python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.i686
[root@texas pycurl-7.19.0]# 




[root@texas /]# locate libcurl.so
/usr/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.1.1


[root@texas /]# locate pycurl
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.6.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl.so
/usr/share/doc/python-pycurl-7.19.0
```

I've recompiled my directadmin build with curl and no change after that either. (I already had directadmin with curl working fine before)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Rubens thanks, did not know. When I first asked a question here somebody told me not to do that, so I took that to memory. I have accepted an answer on all my questions now. Now any help here is appreciated, lost.

Comment: Is the time on your server correct via the date command? Are you using zend? Have you run ldconfig?

Comment: @Forrest
[root@texas supa]# ldconfig
[root@texas supa]# yum update
Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version
Aborted
[root@texas supa]# date
Wed Jan  9 05:40:03 MSK 2013
[root@texas supa]# 


Zend optimizer is enabled.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that VMWare Toolkit caused this issue on CentOS VMs.

## vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/vmware-tools-libraries.conf

and add the following two lines at the top (assuming you're 64-bit):

/lib64
/usr/lib64

Save, and "ldconfig".

Comment: I'm use Virtual Box,its' still ok.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue. Someone just played with LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH; yum update
```

or

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='' yum update
```

does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Reached here from google. So just for future viewers, if I use yum without root permission, I was getting this error. Using `sudo yum` fixed it. I am using CentOS 7.9.2009.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after having added a bunch of libraries to the `ldconfig` path.  (I needed to install the `RPostgreSQL` in my local R install, and was missing `libpq.so` and some others; I happened to have a package that had all that --and more-- and simply added the libs of that package via `ldconfig`; that royally screwed up `yum` and `pycurl` etc.)

So, I just selected the **minimal set of libs** I wanted and added them to some place in `/usr/local/lib/rpostgresql-depend`, then added that via `ldconfig`.  Now both that RPostgreSQL package in R and `yum` work.

Your problem might be a variation of this.

Answer (score 0):

My error is very simple.

remove  /usr/local/curl/lib/  from /etc/ld.so.conf  then it's ok.

Comment: My problem is very strange,if you use root role ,it's ok. If you use ordinary user role, you must add sudo .